# Java code is running without stopping in NetBeans (setDefaultCloseOperation)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm a geek and I have started learning Java this year. I have a problem at next code: the program is running but, unfortunately, don't want to stop and to show my window with buttons. I don't understand, way? Please, give me some ideas, I have tried all, but in vain!

```
package arbitru;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public class TogleButon {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window=new JFrame("Name");  
    JPanel Panou=(JPanel) window.getContentPane();
    Panou.setLayout(new FlowLayout());    
    
    JToggleButton button1=new JToggleButton("Button 1", true);    
    Panou.add(button1);
    JToggleButton button2=new JToggleButton("Button 2", false);  
    Panou.add(button2);
    JToggleButton button3=new JToggleButton("Button 3", false);  
    Panou.add(button3);
    
    ButtonGroup Group_button=new ButtonGroup();
    Group_button.add(button1);
    Group_button.add(button2);
    Group_button.add(button3);
    
    
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true); 
    }

}
```

Comment: this code works fine for me but the panel is extra-narrow. Add a `window.pack()` before the `setVisible` line to fit the window size to its component.

Comment: Unrelated: [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)

Comment: Try using a  window.setSize(width, height) if you need to size it differently too.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for your problem is to call `pack()` before calling `setVisible()`.

```java
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.pack(); // Add this line.
window.setVisible(true);
```

The method `pack()` will size the `JFrame` such that it is big enough to display its contained components at their preferred sizes.

Nonetheless you should be aware that your code is not good. You shouldn't construct your GUI in the `main()` method. For learning *Swing* I recommend [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)